# Unable to Delete Html Data table Items

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a html contols data table,In that data table there's a link called Delete.When i click delete i need to delete that item.

Action Link

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "ProductCategory", new { id = item.CategoryId })
```

In my Contoller here i'm going to delete that item,BUT here is the problem is unable to return to the view because there's no any view for Delete Product.Because that Action Link's Data table in another view

```
 public ActionResult DeleteProduct(int id) <-- Id correct here
    {
        return View(_pc.DeleteProduct(id));

    }
```

Actually delete completed i need to redirect it to the Index View.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
return View(_pc.DeleteProduct(id));
```

Use this

```
_pc.DeleteProduct(id);
return RedirectToAction("Index", "ProductCategory");
```

Answer (score 1):

In your ActionLink the second parameter is the name of the Action.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteProduct", new { id = item.CategoryId })
```

If the Index is in the same controller:

```
    public ActionResult DeleteProduct(int id)
    {
        _pc.DeleteProduct(id);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```